# How can I filter my products from my search function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to setup an isotope filtering on my search bar, when someone starts to search the results need to be filtered. I am using another Isotope function on the checkboxes that work but for some reason I cannot get my search bar to work.

Found an example online of how to filter the results but I cannot seem to get it working on my code. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="header">
      <div class="search">
         <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Zoek spel" name="search" id="myinput">
         <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="strategie.html">Strategie</a>
  <a href="fantasie.html">Fantasy</a>
  <a href="deductief.html">Deductieve</a>
  <a href="coop.html">Cooperatief</a>
  <a href="familie.html">Familie</a>
  <a href="kinder.html">Kinder</a>
  <a href="kaartspellen.html">Kaartspellen</a>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

  <section>
 <div id="filtering" class="filterlist">
    <h4>Speelminuten</h4>
        <label class="container-filter"><input type="checkbox" value="15" /> tot 15 min <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container-filter"><input type="checkbox" value="30" /> 15 - 30 min. <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container-filter"><input type="checkbox" value="60" /> 30 - 60 min. <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container-filter"><input type="checkbox" value="90" /> Meer dan 60 min. <span class="checkmark"></span></label>          

  <div class="searchPageText">
    <h1>De leukste bordspellen op Spelplaats.com</h1>
    <p>Vind gemakkelijk het leukste bordspelspel dat bij jou past bij 1 van onze partners. Of je nou van strategische spellen houdt of meer bent van familiespellen op Spelplaats.com vind je jouw bordspel.</p>
  </div> 
<div>
      <div class="productdiv" id="products">
        <ul class="products" id="products">
                <div class="boardgame" data-category="90 3 all 12 Strategie">
                        <li>
                        <img src="img/Catan-Inkas-1.jpg" alt="Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas">
                        <h3>Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas</h3>
                        <a href="catan-rise-of-the-incas.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                        </li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 2 all 8 Family">
                        <li>
                        <img src="img/Carcassonne.jpg" alt="Carcassonne">
                        <h3>Carcassonne</h3>
                        <a href="carcassonne.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                        </li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 2 all 12 Coop">
                        <li>
                        <img src="img/Paranormal-Detectives.jpg" alt="Paranormal Detectives">
                        <h3>Paranormal Detectives</h3>
                        <a href="paranormaldetectives.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                        </li>
                        </div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
  // set up variables
  var qsRegex;
  
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('#products').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.boardgame',
    filter: function() {
            return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
          }
        });
  
// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.myinput').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope();
  }, 200 ) );
  
  // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
  function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    threshold = threshold || 100;
    return function debounced() {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
      var args = arguments;
      var _this = this;
      function delayed() {
        fn.apply( _this, args );
      }
      timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
    };
  }
```

Comment: what is exactly your problem?

Comment: My problem is that when I am typing within the search bar I do not see any filtering happening (my product list is bigger then in my example)

Comment: you should give a sample your result you are waiting when you type something

Answer (score 0):

difficult to see if you have have more errors without a reproductible sample, but in first analysis, you do a mixture between class and id:

instead to write `$('.myinput').keyup`, write `$('#myinput').keyup`

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the result of your search when you want to filter, and besides that you're calling `$grid.isotope();` but `$grid` should be `$container`.

```
var $container = $('#products').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.boardgame',
});
```

In the `keyup` listener use the value of the search to set the filter. Change the element selector to `#myinput`. Your input has an id instead of a class.

The filter will use jQuery selectors to try and identify the elements. The easiest way to accomplish this is to turn your values into class selectors, for example: `.Family` or `.Strategie.all.3`.

To do that, split all words at the spaces, loop over each word and prepend a `.` to the word, then combine them back together to a single string. Now you have a class selector.

```
var $quicksearch = $('#myinput').on('keyup', debounce(function() {
  var searchValue = $quicksearch.val(); // Get typed value.
  var splitValues = searchValue.split(' '); // Split to array at every space.
  var classSelectors = splitValues.map(function(value) { // Add . to every word
    return '.' + value;
  });
  var filterValue = classSelectors.join(''); // Combine words to a single string.

  $container.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
}, 200));
```

In the current state your HTML is not valid. `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements can only have a `<li>` as a direct child. Any other element is not valid.

Also remove your `data-category` attribute. Add those values to the `class` attribute instead as Isotope will try to identify the elements that you filter with classes.

```
<ul class="products" id="products">
  <li class="boardgame 90 3 all 12 Strategie">
    <div>
      <img src="img/Catan-Inkas-1.jpg" alt="Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas"/>
      <h3>Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas</h3>
      <a href="catan-rise-of-the-incas.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="boardgame 30 2 all 8 Family">
    <div>
      <img src="img/Carcassonne.jpg" alt="Carcassonne" />
      <h3>Carcassonne</h3>
      <a href="carcassonne.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="boardgame 30 2 all 12 Coop">
    <div>
      <img src="img/Paranormal-Detectives.jpg" alt="Paranormal Detectives" />
      <h3>Paranormal Detectives</h3>
      <a href="paranormaldetectives.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```